# Move onclick="touch(event) from .html to Javascript file

Tags: javascript

I have a div in my .htlm file as so:

```
<div id="touch" onclick="touch(event)"></div>
```

How can I make this div in the .html file like this:

```
<div id="touch"></div>
```

And then in my .js file I wish to make it "on click" within an "if" statement: (I have a switch in a config.js file for the "enableTouch")

```
if (enableTouch == true) {
document.getElementById('touch')...what do I need to put in here to activate the on click?

Animation code here.

}
```

Thanks.

Still doesn't work:
It works if I take out:

```
"document.getElementById('touch').onclick = touch;"
```

and change the div in the .html to:

```
<div id="touch" onclick="touch(event)"></div>
```

Thanks again.

```
//if ((EnableTouchToDisplayHourlyForecast == true) && (AnimationsOnly == false)) {

document.getElementById('touch').onclick = touch;

var touchend = false;
function touch(event) {
var element = event.currentTarget;
    if(touchend){
        touchend=false;

        document.getElementById("forecastContainer").style.opacity="1.0";
        document.getElementById("forecastContainer").style.webkitTransform="scale(1.0,1.0)";

        document.getElementById("hourlyForecastContainer").style.opacity="0.0";
        document.getElementById("hourlyForecastContainer").style.webkitTransform="scale(0.0,0.0)";

    }else{

        touchend=true;

        document.getElementById("forecastContainer").style.opacity="0.0";
        document.getElementById("forecastContainer").style.webkitTransform="scale(0.0,0.0)";

        document.getElementById("hourlyForecastContainer").style.opacity="1.0";
        document.getElementById("hourlyForecastContainer").style.webkitTransform="scale(1.0,1.0)";
    }    
}
//}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
if (enableTouch) {
    document.getElementById('touch').onclick = touch;
}
```

If the JS script is included before the body of your page, you'll need to do this in the `onload` handler:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (enableTouch) {
        document.getElementById('touch').onclick = touch;
    }

    // other onload stuff
};

var touchend = false;
function touch(event) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I answered you in post 1 as can't post code anymore, thanks for looking.